# Create a Mirrored control in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight-3.0, mirroring

I want to be able to dynamically mirror a silverlight control.
suppose i have a stackpanel and two buttons inside | >>(button1) | >(button2) |

When i flip it, the result will be |< (button 2)|<< (button1)|

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, create a planeprojection on the control and add a rotationY of 180 degrees.